# Best Way To Set Up Ruby/Java Build/Deploy?

Tags: java, ruby, tomcat, deployment, build-automation

I have a project which is going to use Ruby on the front end, and have JRuby call some needed Java libraries on the back-end.

If this was just a Java application, I would set up an ant script that would make a .war file and be done with it.

Since I am using Ruby, JRuby and Java, what is a good way of setting up the build and deploy process that would ultimately live on Tomcat?

Will the SQLLite db work well on Tomcat?  Do I need to do anything extra so that the Ruby code lives on localhost:8080 instead of rails server which is localhost:3000 ?

And will I be able to run the rails framework on Tomcat?

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Trinidad Gem](http://github.com/trinidad/trinidad_init_services) is basically to tomcat what the Glassfish gem was to the Glassfish java container.  It is based on tomcat and sounds like it might suit your purposes.  As far as deployment you can also use the warbler gem to create war files to deploy your code as well.

Comment: @James I like your website's domain name :)

Comment: @Genadinik thanks, I do it every day!  Was I able to help answer your question at all? Heres another question that was kind of similar [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/147671/whats-the-best-way-to-deploy-a-jruby-on-rails-application-to-tomcat)

Comment: @James I think I am still not clear how to set up the structure of the dev and server environment with JRuby and Java libraries.  Warbler helped, but the directory structure seems to be a mess :) Here is another question I posted that I still have a problem with: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5794112/getting-the-application-structure-correct-when-using-warbler-to-make-a-war

Comment: @Genadinik, I'm not an expert but played with this a few times, I posted an answer on the other question.  Hopefully it helps... Good luck!

Comment: @James so when someone tells you "oh, go take a hike" you take it as a compliment? :-)

Comment: I do it every day...but you're right every now and then I need to take a hike :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe that netbeans had support to deploy rails apps on Java EE app servers... Maybe that's a starting point.

Comment: sadly, I think netbeans has  [killed support for jruby :(](http://netbeans.org/community/news/show/1507.html)