# Compile all .rb files of a Ruby on Rails app to .class using JRuby, pack it into a .war and deploy into a Java appserver

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, ruby, jruby, jrubyonrails

Is it possible to compile all .rb source files files (including the configuration source file files) of Ruby on Rails to .class files using JRuby, pack it into a .war file and deploy to JBoss or another Java appserver?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/147671/whats-the-best-way-to-deploy-a-jruby-on-rails-application-to-tomcat

Comment: It's not a duplicate... I don't want to simply pack my Ruby files into a .war and deploy to a Java appserver, I want to also compile my .rb files to .class files - I want to hide my ruby source code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [warbler](http://kenai.com/projects/warbler/pages/Home) for this purpose.

From the main page:

> Warbler is a gem that makes a .war file out of a Rails, Merb, or
>   Rack-based application. The intent is to provide a minimal, flexible,
>   ruby-like way to bundle all your application files for deployment to a
>   Java application server.

Comment: I don't want to simply pack my Ruby files into a .war and deploy to a Java appserver, I want to also compile my .rb files to .class files - I want to hide my ruby source code.

Comment: warbler will do all you are asking including making .class files.

Comment: actually, if you open the war file, you still see the ruby code.

Answer (score 0):

the following command should compile all .rb to .class

```
warble compiled
```

in the warble.rb file you can uncomment the line to compile only some Ruby files

```
# config.compiled_ruby_files = FileList['app/**/*.rb']
```